# how to redirect user from viewing a page with no token php

Tags: php

I am trying to write an php page that will use a token system to be viewed currently i have my page but I can't secure it if you visit the url with no token it throw some errors about undefined variable i need to redirect  the person visiting without the creditianls to an error page rather than having the serve through undefined variable T any help towards the right direction on how to use the if (issert) statement to check please

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck fixing it. We obviously can't help, since you've provided (almost) nothing useful, like actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && your_token_check_function($_GET["token"])) {
    display_page();
}
else {
    display_error();
}
```